# Animating Subview's Frame In A UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiscrollview

I have a subview inside a **horizontal UIScrollView**.

The subview's frame changes when a **vertical UISwipeGestureRecognizer** is triggered.

However, **if the user swipes diagonally by mistake, the subview's frame does not really change.**

Well, technically it does, but you see a very quick flash - where *you see it change but then immediately go back to its original frame*.

The scrollview has paging enabled - so maybe it goes back to the current page's location?

**How do I get the subview's frame to change (without reverting back)?**

I have tried using various options like UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews. Currently I am calling `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animation:completion` when a vertical swipe is registered

Answer (score 0):

You should try using CGRectMake at the end of your method.

```
subview.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
```

Comment: I'm already doing this in animateWithDuration. Keeping this at the end of the animation method, defeats the purpose of animating the frame. The problem here is that the scrollview is interfering with the animation.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to do here.  Maybe you should disable scrolling during your animation, then enable it again when the animation has completed.

Comment: I do that. Thanks for trying to help, it's a strange bug. :)